# Stop vscode from reformating in one file

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I want to stop reformating just in one file. I know I can disable it for all projects/ whole project, but only one file interests me
Thank you in advance

Comment: What kind of reformatting are we talking about? Maybe it is possible to give hints to the formatter about how you want to format this specific piece of code?

Comment: It reformats my lists (which are arguments of function) really bad

Comment: Could you provide an example?